# Perl Script Closes Python after each run: How to keep Python Open

Tags: python, perl

I am running a perl script, which loops through each directory, where I run a Python GUI, and once I finish my work in that directory, I close the GUI, and I move on to the next event.  However, Python closes every time I complete a run in a directory.  I was wondering how to keep python open, to decrease the processing time with opening python.  The Code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
#
#
# This scirpt will open AIMBAT automatically so that I don't have
# to change directories every time I open AIMBAT.


# Read in the List of Event Files
open(TABLEA, "eventList");
@tablea = <TABLEA>;
# Change the Home directory to whatever directory events are located.
$homeD = "/Users/grbrenn/antarctica/TAMSEIS/response_removed/";
# Takes each line in the array, tablea/eventList, and runs the script
for ($i = 0; $i < @tablea; $i++) {
    chomp ($tablea[$i]);
    ($event) = (@tablea[$i])[0];
    chdir $event;
    system("ttpick.py *BHZ");
    chdir $homeD;
    print
}
```

Comment: Why not just open the eventList (or whatever you're reading and looping over) *inside* your python script, instead of repeatedly calling python from a perl script?

Comment: Perl doesn't "close" Python. The Python program exits all on its own. You're first going to have to change your Python script first.